# how to implement ruby on rails Observer for remote database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a requirement to observe a remote database table. I am looking at code like the following:

```
class RemotetableObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  # Need to watch the remote table
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "remoteDB"
  observe :remotetable 

  def after_create(row)
    doStuff.create(row)
  end
end
```

I have added

```
config.active_record.observers = :remotetable_observer
```

to my application.rb config file, and my database.yml connects to the remote database.

I am getting `NameError: uninitialized constant remotetable` so I created a further model:

```
# remotetable.rb   
class Remotetable < ActiveRecord::Base
  # establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["otherdb_#{RAILS_ENV}"])
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "remoteDB"
  self.table_name = "remotetable"
end
```

but still getting the same error: `NameError: uninitialized constant remotetable`

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a requirement to observe a remote database table.

ActiveRecord observers do not observe tables, they observe objects. So when you update a user, it can observe that the user is updating and inject itself into the user lifecycle.

For you to act upon a foreign transaction that you do not have control over will require hooking into that database, using a trigger or pub/sub if available.

Comment: so I can't hook into the remote rails database / remote rails environment and use an observer because an observer can't observe remote rails objects?

Comment: Correct. you would need to add an observer to the remote rails project that acts upon when THAT rails project updates its objects.